# Reducing Spaces: Complement

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider an operator:
$$T:\mathcal{D}(T)\to\mathcal{H}:\quad\overline{\mathcal{D}(T)}=\mathcal{H}$$

Regard a subspace:
$$\mathcal{S}\leq\mathcal{H}:\quad\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{S}\oplus\mathcal{S}^\perp$$

Can it happen that:
$$T\mathcal{S}\subseteq\mathcal{S}\quad T\mathcal{S}^\perp\nsubseteq\mathcal{S}^\perp$$
Does someone have an example at hand?

Comment: Hint: Consider $2\times 2$ matrices that are not diagonalizable.

Comment: Like the standard example?

Comment: Got it, thanks! :)

Comment: @user161825: Is there also an example of a *normal* operator?

Comment: Chapter 9 of the book 'A Course in Functional Analysis' by Conway is titled 'Invariant Subspaces for Normal Operators'. I think it will be of interest to you.

Comment: @user161825: Ok so not every (bounded) normal operator is reductive, right? Therefore they have an invariant subspace that is not reducing.

Comment: Yes, such bounded normal operators exist.

Comment: @user161825: Thanks for your hint!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nilpotents**

Consider the nilpotent matrix:
$$N:=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
Regard the closed subspace:
$$\mathcal{S}:=\{\begin{pmatrix}a\\0\end{pmatrix}:a\in\mathbb{C}\}$$
Then it fails to reduce:
$$N\mathcal{S}\subseteq\mathcal{S}\quad N\mathcal{S}^\perp\nsubseteq\mathcal{S}^\perp$$

**Ladders**

Consider the annihilation operators:
$$a(\eta):\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{h})\to\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{h}):\quad a(\eta)\bigotimes_{i=1}^k\sigma_i:=\langle\eta,\sigma_n\rangle\bigotimes_{i=1}^{k-1}\sigma_i$$
Regard the bosonic resp. fermionic Fock space:
$$\mathcal{F}^\pm_0(\mathcal{h}):=P^\pm\mathcal{F}_0(\mathcal{h})$$
Though invariant they fail to be reducing as:
$$P^\pm a(\eta)P^\pm=a(\eta)P^\pm\quad a(\eta)P^\pm\neq P^\pm a(\eta)$$
*(Note that for creation operators they're not even invariant.)*

**Hamiltonians**

For Hamiltonians:
$$H=H^*:\quad H\mathcal{S}\subseteq\mathcal{S}\implies H\mathcal{S}^\perp\subseteq\mathcal{S}^\perp$$

That follows from:
$$\psi\in\mathcal{S}^\perp\cap\mathcal{D}:\quad\langle H\psi,\chi\rangle=\langle\psi,H\chi\rangle=0\quad(\chi\in\mathcal{S}\cap\mathcal{D})$$

And assertion follows by density.